# How to deploy weblogic application as docker container completely using Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, weblogic, weblogic12c

I've a simple REST API in the weblogic application. I've to deploy the application as the docker container. But, I'm facing a problem in defining the Dockerfile.

> Dockerfile

```
FROM store/oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.4
COPY target/app.war /u01/oracle
```

Above is my current `Dockerfile`. With the current dockerfile, I have to manually deploy the application on the weblogic server. We would like to automate the application deployment using `Dockerfile` and didn't get the exact examples.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex task, so it is hard to explain the whole process here.

The high-level steps that you need to execute are the followings:

1. Start a properly configured WebLogic domain in Docker. This task involves the creation of the admin and managed servers and WL cluster, etc.
2. Build the application that you wanna deploy
3. Configure the database properly if you have any
4. Create the WL resources like connection pool, JMS, etc manually or via WLST script
5. Deploy your artifact via the WL web console or with WLST script or copy the file under the `autodeploy` directory

Be careful because the tasks that you executed manually will be lost if you drop your docker container.

You can find concrete examples, use cases, automated scripts that you can use and well prepared, ready for use WebLogic Docker images here: https://github.com/zappee/docker-images

If you have a concrete question, not a general one, like this, then please start a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the GitHub project:

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles